# Does "isProbablePrime" really need to spend most time reading files?

Tags: java, random

I've just solved [the Project Euler Problem 60](http://projecteuler.net/problem=60), but my program is still a bit too slow. I've found out that most of the time gets spend in reading from a file...

It looks like `BigInteger.isProbablePrime` uses `SecureRandom` which reads from a Linux device all the time. My questions are:

- Is it really necessary to use `SecureRandom`?
- Does `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` get used?
- Is reading them from the OS really the best way for generating good random numbers?

AFAIK, java used to get a few bytes from the OS which were used as a seed of an SHA1-based PRNG, which should IMHO be faster.

Comment: Which implementation of the Java API are you using?

Comment: These days I think most high level functions from things in java produce pretty good random numbers IMO. 

It still doesn't explain why it is taking so long to access /dev/random though - it would be interesting to see if your code speeds up using a different approach.

You could always try reading some gargbage out of memory and converting it to an int to use as a seed, but because you are using java that might be a bit tricky.

In the past I have used the system clock for a seed, but I didn't require random to be every unpredicatable at that stage.

Comment: Reading garbage out of random memory will cause undefined behavior and likely make you prone to a general protection fault.

Comment: @veer: I'm using Oracle Java version "1.7.0_06" on Linux 2.6.32-42 (Ubuntu 10.4, i5-2400).

Answer (score 1):

> Is reading them from the OS really the best way for generating good random numbers?

I don't know about `isProbablePrime` but `SecureRandom` tries to get a random number via the corresponding OS function that has really good properties for random functions.
In Linux this happens by two virtual devices `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` and when you read from the files, the bits are unpredictably random and are generated based on events happening to the system.

> Does /dev/random or /dev/urandom get used?

Actually this is configurable and you can see this.
Open the `security.properties` file in your `lib\security` of your JRE. There is a configuration entry there. In my installation `/dev/urandom` is specified.

The difference between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` is that `/dev/random` *blocks* if new random bits are not available

Answer (score 0):

Both BigInteger and SecureRandom are overkill (and slow) for Euler 60.  For this kind of problem you don't need the cryptographic properties of SecureRandom; ordinary Random will serve perfectly well.

The largest number in the answer is well below the range where you would need to use BigInteger.  For my solution I used Eratosthenes to pre-calculate primes up to a limit.  That gave me a fast enough prime test.

Comment: In the meantime I've also created a huge Eratosthenes Sieve, which solved the speed problem. So let's forget about Euler 60; I still wonder what they're doing. You're writing "ordinary Random will serve perfectly well", but how could I use it in `BigInteger.isProbablePrime` if I wanted?

Comment: You would have to rewrite the Java code, or else write your own version of the Miller-Rabin test, which is what I suspect is being used under the hood.  BigInteger.isProbablePrime() can be used in cryptographic code, such as RSA, and so has to be cryptographically secure.  Random is fast, but not secure.  IIRC it only has about 48 bits of security, while a secure PRNG needs at least 128 bits or more.  Hence the slower speed, it is doing a lot more work with a larger internal state.

Comment: *Random has zero security:* 1. It gets seeded rather predictably, so it's unusable for crypto. 2. It has only 48 bits of state, and that's not enough as you wrote. 3. After seeing a few values, the seed can be extracted and the whole sequence computed. Even backwards.